# Magento 2 Minicart template not changing on front end

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I want to style the minicart in my Magento 2 store. When I edit /Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html none of the changes show up in the cart. Is that a caching issue? or am I editing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a static file. It is deployed content. Its rendered from the pub/static folder.